# "Questions", Construction with "do" and "be"

Tags: questions

I always tend to use constructions like in the examples below. Where I'm mixing "do" and "be" by way similar to that when the "do" and "have" are used together. (e.g. Does it have?). Why it is wrong? How it break the sense of what I want to say by it?

> a) Does the feature is still available?
>
> b) Do markets are open?

Thank you.

Comment: Both of your examples are wrong. It would rather be **"Is the feature still available?"** and **"Are the markets open?"**. Try putting correct examples so your question can be understood more easily

Comment: Anyway, if you could do this, you'd need to use the bare infinitive _be,_ so _does the feature still be available?_ and _do markets be open?_  These are still somewhat weird, but they're not as wrong as the example sentences.  Consider your analogy with _have:_ we conjugate _do,_ not _have,_ which is why we don't say _*does it has?_

Answer (score 1):

You can form sentences that use either *do* or *is*, but generally not both at the same time. As a simple rule, pick only one or the other:

> ✘ Does the feature is still available?
>
> → ✔ Is the feature still available?
>   → ✔ Does the feature still exist?

With the *does* version, you can't use the word *available*, so I changed it to something else.

> ✘ Do markets are open?
>
> → ✔ Are the markets open [now]?
>   → ✔ Do the markets open [at 9:00]?

I added the definite article in front of *feature*. I also added the words in parentheses to illustrate the different meanings of the two sentences.

Comment: Shouldn't the fourth word be "questions"?  The phrases "do be" and "don't be" are fairly common.

Answer (score 0):

- You play **the guitar**. (**do play**)

  - Do you play **the guitar**?

    - **What** do you do? (play the guitar = do. What, put **what** at the beginning of the sentence)
- You have got **a camera** in your bag.   (**have got**)

  - Have you got **a camera** in your bag? (put **have** at the beginning of the sentence)

    - **What** have you got in your bag.(**a camera** = **what** , put **what **at beginning of the sentence)
- You have **a camera** in your bag. (**do have**)

  - Do you have **a camera** in your bag？(put **do** at the beginning of the sentence)

    - **What** do you have in your bag? (**a camera** = **what** , put **what** at the beginning of the sentence)

Comment: Please take care of the way you use punctuation marks. We do not include two spaces neither before or after a comma, nor a question mark. Also, there is an edit option in the answer you post, no need to delete and write all over again.

Answer (score -1):

**To do** and **to be** never<sup>* *(see below)*</sup> mix in the same clause / sentence. Either of them is enough, depending on the context.

Your examples will be OK like this:

> a) **Is** the feature still available?

> b) **Are** the markets open?

If your question must use **to be**, then **to do** is no longer needed.

However, if your sentence does not have / does not need **to be**, then **to do** is needed:

> **Do** you **have** some time?

> **Did** you **go** to the concert?

---

Additionally,never mix **to do** with the modal verbs: **can** / **may** / **must**:

> <strike>**Do** you **can**</strike> sing?

> **Can** you sing?>

or:

> <strike>**Do** I **may**</strike> wait here?

> **May** I wait here?

To form an interrogation with **must**, then you need to use **to have to**, and therefore use **to do**:

> <strike>**Do** I **must**</strike> pay?

> **Do** I **have to** pay?

---

(*) One exception when "to do" and "to be" fit together in a sentence is when  "to do" has the purpose to emphasize the action (in this case, "to be").

As @phoog so cleverly provided an example in the comment:

> Do be careful not to mislead anyone.

Comment: Do be careful not to mislead anyone.

Comment: @phoog: Very good point, I missed that usage. I updated my answer to include this.Thank you.